# Pygame how to set up collision in my game, I dont understand it

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I just cant wrap my head around the concept of collisions, now I know I am asking a lot but I will appreciate it greatly!, All I ask is someone to add collisions to my game and explain each step so I can try to understand whats going on,I tried youtube videos and they aren't explained very well or I just get overwhelmed which is what I feel right now, So I just want the player to stop when hitting the tree, something as simple as that! And if possible I want it to get the collision from a list for example I would have trees and other images in the list.

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
from pygame.locals import *
import tiles_list

pygame.init()
display_w = 800
display_h = 600

window = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("game_icon.png"))
pygame.display.set_caption("Work in progress")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")


class Player(object):
    """The controllable player in game"""

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprite_sheet.png")
        self.speed = speed
        self.timer = 0
        self.frames = 1
        self.direction = 2

    def animation(self):
        x_coord = 50 * self.frames
        y_coord = 50 * self.direction
        self.character = self.image.subsurface(x_coord, y_coord, self.width, self.height)

        self.timer += 0
        if self.timer >= 10:
            self.timer = 0
            self.frames += 1
            if self.frames >= 9:
                self.frames = 1

    def draw(self):
        window.blit(self.character, (self.x, self.y))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def movement(self):
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or self.keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.x -= self.speed
            self.direction = 1
            self.timer += 2
        if self.keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or self.keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.x += self.speed
            self.direction = 3
            self.timer += 2
        if self.keys[pygame.K_UP] or self.keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.y -= self.speed
            self.direction = 0
            self.timer += 2
        if self.keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or self.keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.y += self.speed
            self.direction = 2
            self.timer += 2
        if self.x >= 780:
            self.x = 780
            self.frames = 0
        if self.y >= 555:
            self.y = 555
            self.frames = 0
        if self.x <= 0:
            self.x = 0
            self.frames = 0
        if self.y <= 0:
            self.y = 0
            self.frames = 0


player = Player(400, 300, 50, 50, 4.5)


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.image = (
            pygame.transform.scale(tiles_list.tiles.subsurface(pygame.Rect(99, 147, self.width, self.height)),
                                   (62, 82)))

    def draw(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


tree = Tree(348, 300, 42, 62)

running = True
while running:
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), RESIZABLE)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if player.keys:
                player.frames = 0

    dist_x = math.hypot(tree.x - player.x)
    dist_y = math.hypot(tree.y - player.y)  # Does nothing except calculate the distence
    print("distx", dist_x, "disty", dist_y)

    tree.draw()
    player.movement()
    player.animation()
    player.draw()

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: why dont you use dist_x and dist_y if they are  = 0 then your required thing. Or else you can check when they come to same pixel range

Comment: How would I stop the movement of the character setting x or y to 0 would just teleport the sprite to the top left corner and also this wouldnt be accurate enough and clipping would happen, I did think about using it but I have no idea on what to do with it

Comment: See [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all I suggest that you start to try to implement the collision test, **before you ask a question**. If you get stuck, you can ask a question about the code that gets you stuck.
Anyway I'll give you some hints.

In common the collision detection is based on [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). For instance create a rectangle from [`pygaem.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects `player.image` and `tree.image` by [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect). Evaluate if the 2 objects are colliding by [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect):

```py
player_rect = player.image.get_rect(topleft = (player.x, player.y))
tree_rect = tree.image.get_rect(topleft = (tree.x, tree.y))
if player_rect.colliderect(tree_rect):
    print("hit")
```

If you *"just want the player to stop when hitting the tree"*, the store the position of the player and move the player. After that evaluate if the player hits the tree. If the player is hitting, then restore the position:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    # store position of player
    player_pos = (player.x, player.y)
    
    # move player
    player.movement()

    player_rect = player.image.get_rect(topleft = (player.x, player.y))
    tree_rect = tree.image.get_rect(topleft = (tree.x, tree.y))
    
    # test collision of player and tree
    if player_rect.colliderect(tree_rect):

        # restore player position
        (player.x, player.y) = player_pos
```

---

See also [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152)

Comment: Hello! to answer your first question, I got overwhelmed with how many people did theirs I know code can look completely different but do the same job which was what was hurting my head, but this looks amazing because I understand since its using my code! I only have one issue which I actually have a rough clue on fixing, pretty much the tree image is well on a tile sheet so when I try to go around it I cant because its trying to find 0 , 0 on the axis which is completely blank, any clues on fixing this?

Comment: sorry I don't no if you read my last comment since I was in mid editing it, also thank you very much for adding # to the code It makes it easier for me to remember since I am a beginner

Comment: @Dragon20C Please note, neither I can see the images, nor I can test, the code, because it is not complete. All I can do is use my experience to guess. But the sentence *"it I cant because its trying to find 0 , 0 on the axis "* exceeds my imagination

Comment: sorry I wrote that without thinking, pretty much the tree is drawn with a extended rect, here is a gif for visuals, in the gif I am trying to move to the middle https://media.giphy.com/media/hrpyEtaN7mNR5wOPb3/giphy.gif

Comment: @Dragon20C So actually the image is much bigger than the tree? Why? You copy a part form the sheet (`tiles_list.tiles.subsurface`), isn't it?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I have a sprite sheet that has multiple sprite art, it's the same for the player but for the player its made different for animation purposes, would I need to make a custom rect instead of it trying to load the full image? I did cut it but I'm not sure why it has the extra bit hmm.

Comment: Okay it took some time but I figured it out, its not the tree its the player!, the player.image is a full 500 x 500 resolution picture so I couldnt pass the tree creating a custom rect made it work!

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to explain you the process of collisions.
In your game you have two objects - the tree and the player. So, you can say that if the x and y coordinates of the player are the same , then there occurs a collisions. You can use this concept and create variables for detecting collisions.
Thanks

Comment: I understand the concept of when it reaches 0 stop movement but the x and y are only one point on the screen meaning it would clip how would I get a rectangle instead of a dot, I guess I should of said how the game looks, its like a pokemon game style.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you wish to do??